# Ramda.js group by key with unique values

Tags: ramda.js

[I have the following ramda code](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%20%28prop%20%28%27category%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%20%28map%20%28prop%28%27type%27%29%29%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%22category%22%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20%22type%22%20%3A%20%22a_1%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22category%22%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20%22type%22%20%3A%20%22a_1%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22category%22%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20%22type%22%20%3A%20%22a_2%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22category%22%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20%22type%22%20%3A%20%22b_1%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22category%22%3A%20%22b%22%2C%20%22type%22%20%3A%20%22b_1%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0Atransform%28data%29%0A) and The values are not unique

```js
const transform = pipe(
  groupBy (prop ('category')),
  map (map (prop('type'))) //uniq is not working here
)

const data = [
  {"category": "a", "type" : "a_1"},
  {"category": "a", "type" : "a_1"},
  {"category": "a", "type" : "a_2"},
  {"category": "b", "type" : "b_1"},
  {"category": "b", "type" : "b_1"},
]
                                   
const result = transform(data)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map } = R</script>
```

The result is: `{"a": ["a_1", "a_1", "a_2"], "b": ["b_1", "b_1"]}`
The expected : `{"a": ["a_1", "a_2"], "b": ["b_1"]}`

Tanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After mapping the `type`, pipe the items into `R.uniq`:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map, uniq } = R

const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('category')),
  map(pipe(map(prop('type')), uniq))
)

const data = [{"category":"a","type":"a_1"},{"category":"a","type":"a_1"},{"category":"a","type":"a_2"},{"category":"b","type":"b_1"},{"category":"b","type":"b_1"}]

const result = transform(data)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You can also replace `map(prop('type'))` with `R.pluck`:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map, pluck, uniq } = R

const transform = pipe(
  groupBy(prop('category')),
  map(pipe(pluck('type'), uniq))
)

const data = [{"category":"a","type":"a_1"},{"category":"a","type":"a_1"},{"category":"a","type":"a_2"},{"category":"b","type":"b_1"},{"category":"b","type":"b_1"}]

const result = transform(data)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```